# I can't install Asp.Net Core Packages in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have installed the tool packages but I cannot install the remaining Entity packages. I'm getting an error.

***Please Help !!!***

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First of all, you should check the versions, can you check the project version or tool p. version ? Default latest **version is 7>**